# Maximize div in center of viewport but keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, layout, viewport, centering

This is what I'm looking for:

[image: example]

The `<div>` adjusts in size depending on the viewport size, but it always keeps its aspect ratio.

This is how far I've come:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
div#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<div>` is centered and maxed, but it always has 1:1 aspect ratio. What do I do if I want 2:1 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve it by combining `max-width` and `max-height`.

Below is an example for 2:1 aspect ratio. First, we want `width: 100vw` to fill the full width and (due to 2:1) `height` half of that, so `height: 50vw`. However, if the viewport width gets  wider and viewport height decreases, at some point `50vw` is going to be bigger than the viewport height. This is covered by `max-height: 100vh`. So the height never gets bigger than the viewport height. The same works for the width: `max-width: 200vh` limits the width to double (due to 2:1) the maximum size of the height, which was `100vh`.

For 4:3 aspect ratio, it would be 3/4=0.75 `height: 75vw` and 4/3=1.33 `max-width: 133vh` and so on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<style>
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
div#content {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 200vh;
  height: 50vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```